# Logistic Regression Loss Function: Scikit Learn vs Glmnet

Tags: regression, logistic, scikit-learn, loss-functions, glmnet

The loss function in [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression) is

$$\min_{w,c}{\frac{1}{2}w^Tw+C\sum_{i=1}^N{\log(\exp(-y_i(X_i^Tw+c))+1)}}$$

Whereas the loss function in [glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet.pdf) is

$$\min_{\beta,\beta_0}{-\bigg[\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N{y_i(\beta_0 + x_i^T\beta) - \log(1+e^{\beta_0 + x_i^T\beta})}\bigg] + \lambda[(1-\alpha)||\beta||_2^2/2+\alpha||\beta||_1]}$$

When setting $\alpha=0$, this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203816/logistic-regression-scikit-learn-vs-glmnet) states that they differ by a factor of $\lambda$ if $C=\frac{1}{N\lambda}$, but I can't seem to work this out. From the loss function in glmnet and changing the variable names and notations to match that of scikit-learn, I get

$$\begin{align} &\min_{w,c}{-\bigg[\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N{y_i(X_i^Tw+c) - \log(1+\exp({X_i^Tw+c}))}\bigg] + \lambda \frac{1}{2}w^Tw} \\
= &\min_{w,c}{\lambda \frac{1}{2}w^Tw -\bigg[\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N{y_i(X_i^Tw+c) - \log(1+\exp({X_i^Tw+c}))}\bigg]} \\
= &\min_{w,c}{\lambda \frac{1}{2}w^Tw +\bigg[\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N{\log(1+\exp({X_i^Tw+c}))-y_i(X_i^Tw+c)}\bigg]}\\
= &\min_{w,c}{\lambda \frac{1}{2}w^Tw +\bigg[\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N{\log(1+\exp({X_i^Tw+c}))-\log(\exp(y_i(X_i^Tw+c)))}\bigg]} \\
= &\min_{w,c}{\lambda \frac{1}{2}w^Tw +\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N{\log\bigg(\frac{1+\exp(X_i^Tw+c)}{\exp(y_i(X_i^Tw+c))}\bigg)}} \\
= &\min_{w,c}{\lambda \frac{1}{2}w^Tw +\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N{\log\bigg(\frac{1}{\exp(y_i(X_i^Tw+c))} + \frac{\exp(X_i^Tw+c)}{\exp(y_i(X_i^Tw+c))}\bigg)}}\\
= &\min_{w,c}{\lambda \frac{1}{2}w^Tw +\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N{\log\bigg(\exp(-y_i(X_i^Tw+c)) + \frac{\exp(X_i^Tw+c)}{\exp(y_i(X_i^Tw+c))}\bigg)}} \end{align}$$

which is only true if $\frac{\exp(X_i^Tw+c)}{\exp(y_i(X_i^Tw+c))}=1$ but I can't reason for that case. Which step is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired from this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/419193/191114), I think the reason they are different is that they work on different domains. For sklearn, $y_{sklearn}\in\{-1, 1\}$; for glmnet, $y_{glmnet}\in\{0,1\}$. If we plug in $y=-1$ in the sklearn loss function and $y=0$ in that of glmnet, we get the same result. Same for $y=1$.